# Apply class to object iOS

Tags: ios, class

I am creating a custom table view controller because I want to access a search bar on the table view controller.
How can I apply the new class to my existing tableviewcontroller in my story board?

Edit:

Question was answered, for those unclear as to what I was asking, I had an object in interface builder which was using the standard class for that object, and was wondering how to apply a custom class which I made, thanks!

Comment: See the first image of inspector window on this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-general/AbouttheUtilityArea/AbouttheUtilityArea.html First field is `class` where you have to enter custom tableViewController's class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your tableViewController in the Storyboard, and enter your custom class name in the Class field of the Identity Inspector on the right-hand side:

[image: Identity Inspector in Xcode]